# MongoDB C# Query Array of Objects that contain a property value

Tags: c#, mongodb

My documents have an array property in them.  Lets call it arrayProperty something like this:

```
 {
  _id: mongoObjectIdThingy,
  arrayProperty: [
    {string1: "aString",otherProperty:"somethingelse"},
    {string1: "aString2",otherProperty:"somethingelse"}
  ]
}
```

I'm using the mongodb c# driver.   I want to find all documents that contain any of a list of string1 values.  For example say I have a list of strings:

```
["a","b","aString"]
```

I want the query to return the above document.  I've tried this:

```
    var builder = Builders<MyObject>.Filter;

    var listToFind = new List<string>{"a","b","aString"};


    return builder.ElemMatch(o => o.arrayProperty,
        d => listToFind.Contains(d.string1));
```

But got this exception:

> Unsupported filter:
>   Contains(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]))

It seems like I can't do a contains linq expression in the driver's filter expression. How does one write this type of query in mongoDB with C#?

Comment: it works to me, which version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `In` FilterDefinition, which would make your Builder look like this;

```
return Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(
            o => o.arrayProperty,
            Builders<ArrayProperty>.Filter.In(y => y.string1, listToFind));
```

This builds this query

```
db.MyObject.find({ "arrayProperty" : { "$elemMatch" : { "string1" : { "$in" : ["a", "b", "aString"] } } } })
```

To be able to use the Regex you would have to build a different query (I'm not on coffee so this is without any warranty)

```
        var listToFind = new List<string> { "a", "b", "astring" };

        var regexList = listToFind.Select(x => new BsonRegularExpression(x, "i"));

        var filterList = new List<FilterDefinition<MyObject>>();
        foreach (var bsonRegularExpression in regexList)
        {
            FilterDefinition<MyObject> fil = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(o => o.arrayProperty, Builders<ArrayProperty>.Filter.Regex(
                 x => x.string1,
                 bsonRegularExpression));

            filterList.Add(fil);
        }


        var orFilter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Or(filterList);

        var result = collection.Find(orFilter).ToList();
```

Which builds the follow query

```
db.MyObject.find({ "$or" : [{ "arrayProperty" : { "$elemMatch" : { "string1" : /a/i } } }, { "arrayProperty" : { "$elemMatch" : { "string1" : /b/i } } }, { "arrayProperty" : { "$elemMatch" : { "string1" : /astring/i } } }] })
```

Comment: Where is the In Filter definition used in your answer?

Comment: Good point, I wrote the wrong part here. Updated now. @cobolstinks

Comment: hmm having difficulty implementing this.  Is Builders<ArrayProperty> the type of my object array?  or is that some MongoDB driver built in class?

Comment: It's the class I assumed your model had for the `arrayProperty` array. Could your post your models? To answer your question, yes it's the type of your object array.

Comment: ok cool that worked thanks!  However one last wrinkle is i want the search to be case insensitive.  Is there a flag to pass in the In clause for this?

Comment: @cobolstinks Sadly no overload for this however I can whip up something quick before I hit the bed.

Comment: wow you're awesome thanks for sending me down the right path!

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is using "Any" instead of "Contain".

```
return builder.ElemMatch(o => o.arrayProperty,
        d => listToFind.Any(y => y == d.string1));
```